# Return object base on request uri

Tags: php, zend-framework, orm, doctrine-orm, uri

so I have this modular web application that has doctrine2 intergrated with zend framework 1.12.

So I want to return one object base on the request uri, for example: url/api/people/1, which return the person one base on their id.

*side note, I can return all objects of people, I just want to select one object once the user enter's a number.

What I have tried, was to grab the parameter from the url and just pass it through the find function, but doctrine doesn't understand these numbers passed through the uri, and believes they're actions.

```
  if($this->getRequest()->isGet())
  {
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $id = $request->getParam('peopleId');

    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $peopleRepo = $em->getRepository('API\Entity\People');
    $people = $peopleRepo->find(3); //$id goes into find function

      $resultArray[] = 
      [
        'id'         => $people->getId(),
        'firstname'  => $people->getFirstName(),
        'lastname'   => $people->getLastName(),
        "food"       => $people->getFavoriteFood()
      ];
    echo json_encode($resultArray, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    var_dump($people);
```

*****EDIT*****
So I have added code that I can manually find one person, but I want to do that through the url, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$peopleRepo = $em->getRepository('API\Entity\People')->findBy(array('id' => $id));
```

Or

```
$peopleRepo = $em->getRepository('API\Entity\People')->findById($id);
```

See Doctrine docs:
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#by-simple-conditions

Comment: Both of your suggestions are identical to what the question has.

Comment: @Cerad I assume that the problem is that Doctrine could not find the entity but $id in the request is correct. Paul Chu could you give us more info?

Comment: @hokusai so I have edited the post to hopefully answer your question.